# No sound on Ubuntustudio 23.1

Tags: sound, ubuntu-studio, 23.10, jack

I have installed Ubuntu Studio 23.1 on my Acer TravelMate.

I am so confused after playing with QjackCtrl, pipewire, or true Jackd, etc. that I just don't know anymore.

I did a...

```
sudo lspci
```

It found an audio device.

```
Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
```

I have playback device port speakers and profile analog stereo output. Firefox won't give me any sound when playing YouTube. My volume is at 94%.

I have also tried SynthMI and VCVRack.

Results of `inxi -A` :

```
Audio:
 Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel
 API: ALSA v: k6.5.0-14-lowlatency status: kernel-api
 Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.79 status: active
```

I saw something about SOF drivers, but it all was a bit too much for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get youtube audio only and don't mind to work proessional audio maybe you don't need jack or pipewire... please consider shutdown jack or pipewire and use alsa/pulse only...

Ubuntu studio 23.1 uses by default pipewire firefox audio should be ready... please read https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/#audioconfig
If you are using jack, check the briges configuration with studio controls[STUDIO CONTROLS VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihQMu.png) or Qjackclt... and use on terminal "alsamixer"[ALSAMIXER VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWpBa.png) command to try audio levels...

Anyway,the next LTS relase is almost ready you should try it.